# Issue parsing ed25519v1 keys generated by mkp224o

Tags: go, tor

I used mkp224o to generate a key. Afterwards I tried to use Go to parse the key and start a service with Bine. Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to generate the same v3 onion address as mkp224o.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "crypto/ed25519"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/cretz/bine/tor"
    "github.com/ipsn/go-libtor"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)

    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        check(errors.New("need 1 argument"))
    }

    var known ed25519.PrivateKey
    buf, _ := os.ReadFile("/home/user/mkp224o/onions/rocin4w356yd7jadjppabxivaz56z4k2wfvy5xpxieirenda3yt2aiqd.onion/hs_ed25519_secret_key")
    known = bytes.TrimLeft(buf, "== ed25519v1-secret: type0 ==\x00\x00\x00")

    fmt.Println("Starting and registering onion service, please wait a bit...")
    t, err := tor.Start(context.Background(), &tor.StartConf{ProcessCreator: libtor.Creator, DebugWriter: nil})
    check(errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to start tor"))
    defer t.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Minute)
    defer cancel()

    onion, err := t.Listen(ctx, &tor.ListenConf{Version3: true, RemotePorts: []int{80}, Key: known})
    check(errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to create tor service"))
    defer onion.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Please open a Tor capable browser and navigate to http://%v.onion\n", onion.ID)

    http.HandleFunc("/", pathHandler())
    http.Serve(onion, nil)
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func pathHandler() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    }
}
```

Returns:

```
Starting and registering onion service, please wait a bit...
Please open a Tor capable browser and navigate to http://r3jvsuoxe37pn6ik5vjvcxrky37bxsuopo5yn436r5pamjfkz2mkytqd.onion
```

when it should be returning the `rocin4w356yd7jadjppabxivaz56z4k2wfvy5xpxieirenda3yt2aiqd.onion` address that mkp224o generated. What am I missing?

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22497/how-to-convert-a-private-key-generated-with-mkp224o-to-the-regular-ed22419-forma ?

Comment: thanks @mh-cbon ! that did the trick, I had to source the "github.com/cretz/bine/torutil/ed25519" instead